# How to print JSON data?

Tags: jquery

JSON:

```
{"ID":"14","Amount":"6300","Credit_limit":"2017-09-22"}
```

jQuery Code:

```
$("#Message").html("Dear Client, Your bill no."+response.ID+" amount (as per invoice) has been generated. Due date for the payment is (as per credit limit). Thank you for doing business with us. Good Luck.");
```

It showing undefined anyone can please help me How to print JSON data?

Comment: Did you parse your JSON sring?

Comment: Show us the dump of `response`

Comment: Have you checked what the value of `response` is?

Comment: Maybe no tag with id Message is in the html?, if you can show more code could be helpfull

Comment: Rushab, was the answer helpful to you. Please respond to it

Answer (score 0):

First add a `<div>` or any other element as a container with id `Message` and then you can move on to the `JQuery` code where you can parse your JSON and then access the JSON key:

```js
var response = '{"ID":"14","Amount":"6300","Credit_limit":"2017-09-22"}';

response=JSON.parse(response);
$("#Message").html("Dear Client, Your bill no."+response.ID+" amount (as per invoice) has been generated. Due date for the payment is (as per credit limit). Thank you for doing business with us. Good Luck.");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='Message'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if response is JsonString type
 `'{"ID":"14","Amount":"6300","Credit_limit":"2017-09-22"}'` use
 `var obj=JSON.parse(response); obj.id`

---

if response is Json format 
 `{"ID":"14","Amount":"6300","Credit_limit":"2017-09-22"}` use
 `response.id;`

```js
var response={"ID":"14","Amount":"6300","Credit_limit":"2017-09-22"};
var text="Dear Client, Your bill no."+response.ID+" amount (as per invoice) has been generated. Due date for the payment is (as per credit limit). Thank you for doing business with us. Good Luck."
$("#Message").html($("<span/>",{html:text}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Message"></div>
```